# How to allow anonymous along with windowsAuthenticated to access the WebApplication

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, intranet

Is it possible to allow access to webapplication both **windowsAuthenticated** and **anonymous** users? So if user **windowsAuthenticated** I will receive not empty `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, but if user not **windowsAuthenticated** (**anonymous**) access will be allowed too (with an empty `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`).

I used such a web.config `system.web` part:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*,?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Server is `windowsAuthentication enabled=true` and `anonymousAuthentication enabled=true`.
WebApplication is no MVC or such things - plain .aspx.

Currently a have **anonymous** access, but for **windowsAuthenticated** users there is `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` not always contains user name. Sometimes I need to press F5 in browser several times to get `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` filled.

Comment: Is your site properly configured in IIS?

Comment: Site works well with either _windowsAuthentication_ or _anonymous_, not both.